Issue: High Disk Space Usage and Ledger Ingestion Problems in Stellar Captive Core, Horizon after update to 22 version
Problem Description
After updating our Stellar Captive Core and Horizon, we noticed a significant increase in disk usage. Before the update, the node successfully ingested 22 million ledgers without issues. However, following the update, only 1 million ledgers are consuming approximately 2 TB of disk space.
We need help identifying the cause of this issue and suggestions for resolving or optimizing storage usage.
System Configuration
OS: Ubuntu 23.10 (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-44-generic x86_64)
Disk Space: 3 TB

PostgreSQL Configuration
Version: 15.7 (Ubuntu 15.7-0ubuntu0.23.10.1)

Stellar Core Configuration
Package Version: 22.0.0
Git Version: 1cd8b8dca9aeeca9ce45b129cd923992b32dc258
Ledger Protocol Version: 22
Pre-release Version: 0

rs-stellar-xdr:
Package Version: 22.0.0
Git Version: 715003372ea6380044b5a4a02907ff73e56ae9e7
Base XDR Git Version: 529d5176f24c73eeccfa5eba481d4e89c19b1181

Horizon Configuration
Version: 22.0.2
Git Version: 5df7099e675469f409ad1b8ef5bb2a8a19db7f00
Go Version: go1.22.10

Observations

No changes were made to PostgreSQL configurations during the update
process.
Logs do not indicate errors, but disk utilization continues
to grow at an abnormal rate.

